# How to display package / app icon when browsing Cydia repo

Tags: iphone, ios, icons, jailbreak, cydia

I have successfully created a Cydia repo, and am hosting an app that I am developing, and it installs fine, but for some reason I can't get the app icon to display when clicking the package in Cydia.  As of right now the app icon in Cydia looks like the following, [image: no Icon]

The app icon shows when the app is installed on the device, and I was told the app needs to be installed before the icon will show up in Cydia, so I installed the app on my device, but the icon is still not showing up.  I also added the `Icon: file:///` line to the control file.  I can't seem to figure out why the icon isn't showing, as of right now, the control file looks like,

```
Package: com.chrisrjones.KegCop
Name: KegCop
Version: 0.1.3-103
Architecture: iphoneos-arm
Description: A frontend for the Kegbot.org hardware
Homepage: http://www.chrisrjones.com/kegcop/index.php
Depiction: http://www.chrisrjones.com/kegcop/index.php
Maintainer: Chris Jones <chris.r.jones.1983@gmail.com>
Author: Chris Jones <chris.r.jones.1983@gmail.com>
Sponsor:
Section: Applications
Depends: firmware(>= 5.1.1)
Icon: file:///Applications/KegCop.app/icon57x57_flat.png
```

The `Packages` file that is being generated looks like the following if it makes a difference,

```
Package: com.chrisrjones.KegCop
Version: 0.1.3-103
Architecture: iphoneos-arm
Maintainer: Chris Jones <chris.r.jones.1983@gmail.com>
Depends: firmware(>= 5.1.1)
Filename: .//debs/com.chrisrjones.kegcop_0.1.3-103_iphoneos-arm.deb
Size: 426586
MD5sum: 9c45579ecced6191a6f6497bb067c022
Section: Applications
Homepage: http://www.chrisrjones.com/kegcop/index.php
Description: A frontend for the Kegbot.org hardware
```

Comment: @Nate good comment, I did rename my icon file from `icon57x57_flat.png` to `Icon.png` but am still having no luck. :(

Comment: @Nate, yes I tried all of that.  I think it has something to do with my Info.plist file that is being constructed when I build the application in Xcode.

Comment: http://pastie.org/8243607 <-- that's the plist file that is built when I build the Xcode project.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35628/discussion-between-chris-and-nate)

Comment: @Nate care to chat about this?

Comment: @Nate both of those are things I haven't tried. I will give that a shot.

Comment: @Nate I just renamed `Icon` to `Icon.png` in the `Info.plist` file, then I changed `CFBundleIconFile` to `CFBundleIconFiles`, reinstalled the app, closed cydia, reopened cydia and still do not see the icon :/

Comment: @Nate, I renamed `CFBundleIconFile` to `CFBundleIconFiles` and put the `<array>` syntax in there, my `Info.plist` now looks like this, http://pastie.org/8247866

Comment: For future reference, I think [this page](http://www.saurik.com/id/7) is the authoritative reference, that describes the `Icon` attribute in the Packages file, and how to use a custom version of `dpkg-scanpackages` to get it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the `Packages` file makes a difference.

To include `Icon` field in `Packages` file
You need edit [`dpkg-scanpackages`](http://test.saurik.com/macciti/dpkg-scanpackages) script and add `"Icon"` to the end of the array `fieldpri`.

Here is my `fieldpri` used for Cydia repo.

```
my @fieldpri = ('Package','Source','Version','Priority','Section','Essential','Maintainer','Pre-Depends','Depends','Recommends','Suggests','Conflicts','Provides','Replaces','Enhances','Architecture','Filename','Size','Installed-Size','MD5sum','Description','Origin','Bugs','Name','Author','Homepage','Website','Depiction','Icon');
```

Comment: thank you so much for that reply, I will give that a try when I get home.

Comment: This version is provided by saurik: http://test.saurik.com/macciti/dpkg-scanpackages