# How to set TheBigBoss tweak icon?

Tags: ios, repository, jailbreak, tweak, theos

I have recently gotten into jailbroken iOS app development and have developed my first tweak. I am going to submit it to TheBigBoss repo. My question is this: how can I set the tweak icon in the Cydia store? Looking at the submission page on http://thebigboss.org/ I found that there is no place to submit an icon, which tells me that is must be part of the package that I submit. After downloading multiple open source tweaks from http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Open_Source_Projects I still cannot find how to set the tweak icon. Whenever I install my tweak on my device via Theos and look at it in the Cydia store, I just see the stock "drill" icon.

Thanks for bearing with my noobiness!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display package / app icon when browsing Cydia repo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18238385/how-to-display-package-app-icon-when-browsing-cydia-repo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit your deb's control file to add a line like below

```
Icon: urltoyouriconfile
```

This can also be a local URL (with `file://` prefix then the path)
I hope this still works !